# PL/SQL: Creating a grid (like an excel table) with the intersection of 2 selects, one for rows and the other for columns

Tags: plsql

I have 3 sets of values i wish to display

Class

Duration

Students

The columns of the tables are as follows:

table 1: class - duration

table 2: class - student

The data would look like this:

table 1:

```
class - duration
  1   -   6
  2   -   12
  3   -   18
  4   -   24
```

Table 2:

```
class - student
  1   - student 1
  2   - student 2
  2   - student 3
  4   - student 3
```

the return from the select would look like this:

```
+-----------+---+----+----+----+
|           | 6 | 12 | 18 | 24 |
+-----------+---+----+----+----+
| Student 1 | x |    |    |    |
| Student 2 |   | x  |    |    |
| Student 3 |   | x  |    | x  |
+-----------+---+----+----+----+
```

thanks for the ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With known durations, you can pivot data like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM ( SELECT student
              , duration
           FROM table1 t
           JOIN table2 t2 ON t.class = t2.class )
PIVOT
(
   count(duration)
   FOR duration IN (6,12,18,24)
)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a8c7bb/57

Other propositions:

- You can create `dynamic query` to fetch duration and create the list.
- You can use `PIVOT XML` and then `extractvalue` into readable data
  but you will need to know the number of returned columns

Comment: @Borja, if it fits your need or help you enough , you can mark the answer as accepted in order to help other people found a solution too.